# How to catch a Streamlit form variable and pass it into Javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, ajax, streamlit

From my simple `Streamlit` contact form, I want to catch *name, email and message* and using `JavaScript` to send them to the owner of the website through `FormSubmit`. This is my code:

```
import streamlit as st
from streamlit.components.v1 import html

form = st.form("myForm", clear_on_submit=True)
name = form.text_input("Full name")
email = form.text_input("Email Address")
msg = form.text_area("Message")

submit = form.form_submit_button("Send")

my_js = """
            var dict_values = {"{{name}}", "{{email}}", "{{msg}}"};
            var s = JSON.stringify(dict_values);
            console.log(s);
            window.alert(s);
            $.ajax({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'https://formsubmit.co/ajax/my-email',
                dataType: 'json',
                accepts: 'application/json',
                data: JSON.stringify(s)
                success: (data) => console.log(data),
                error: (err) => console.log(err)
            });
        """
my_html = f'''<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.js"></script>
                                 <script type="text/javascript">
                                     {my_js}
                                 </script>
           '''
if submit:
   html(my_html)
```

The code is running well, I mean the form, but nothing happens!
I think my problem is the way I passed the variables to `JavaScript`!

Any help/suggestion is very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One of your imports is not appropriate, followed by `$.ajax()` which appeared to have a missing `,` before `success` and also I think your `dict_values` variable is not being assigned correctly. It should use the name, email, and msg variables and use the `:` character to assign values to keys, not the `,` character. It should look like this:

```py
import streamlit as st
import streamlit.components.v1 as components

form = st.form("myForm", clear_on_submit=True)
name = form.text_input("Full name")
email = form.text_input("Email Address")
msg = form.text_area("Message")

submit = form.form_submit_button("Send")

my_js = """
            var dict_values = {"name": "{{name}}", "email": "{{email}}", "msg": "{{msg}}"};
            var s = JSON.stringify(dict_values);
            console.log(s);
            window.alert(s);
            $.ajax({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'https://formsubmit.co/ajax/my-email',
                dataType: 'json',
                accepts: 'application/json',
                data: JSON.stringify(s),
                success: (data) => console.log(data),
                error: (err) => console.log(err)
            });
        """
my_html = f'''<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.js"></script>
              <script type="text/javascript">{my_js}</script>
           '''
if submit:
   components.html(my_html)
```

You can give it a try to see if it fixes your problem. Else you should provide a traceback error message.